# Prob. 14, Sec. 30, in Munkres' TOPOLOGY, 2nd ed: The product of a Lindelof space and a compact space is a Lindelof space

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, compactness, lindelof-spaces

Here is Prob. $14$, Sec. $30$, in the book *Topology* by James R. Munkres, 2nd edition:

> Show that if $X$ is Lindelof and $Y$ is compact, then $X \times Y$ is Lindelof.

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3652735/prob-14-sec-30-in-munkres-topology-2nd-ed-if-x-is-lindelof-and-y-is-c) is my Math Stack Exchange post on this very problem.

In the present post, I seek to give an alternative proof.

My Attempt:

> Let $\pi_1 \colon X \times Y \longrightarrow X$ and $\pi_2 \colon X \times Y \longrightarrow X$ be the projection mappings defined by
> $$
> \pi_1 ( x \times y) := x \qquad \mbox{ and } \qquad \pi_2 ( x \times y) := y.
> $$
> These two mappings are continuous open maps.

> Let $\mathscr{A}$ be any open covering of $X \times Y$ by  the basis elements for the product topology of the form $U \times V$, where $U$ is open in $X$, and $V$ is open in $Y$.

> This open covering $\mathscr{A}$ yields the open coverings $\mathscr{A}_X$ and $\mathscr{A}_Y$ of $X$ and $Y$ respectively, given by
> $$
> \mathscr{A}_X := \left\{ \pi_1 (A) \colon A \in \mathscr{A} \right\} \qquad \mbox{ and } \qquad \mathscr{A}_Y := \left\{ \pi_2 (A) \colon A \in \mathscr{A} \right\}. 
> $$
> Since $X$ is Lindelof and $Y$ is compact, some *countable* subcollection
> $$
> \left\{ \pi_1 \left( A_1 \right), \pi_1 \left( A_2 \right), \pi_1 \left( A_3 \right), \ldots \right\} 
> $$
> of $\mathscr{A}_X$ covers $X$, and some *finite* subcollection
> $$
> \left\{ \pi_2 \left( A_1^\prime \right), \ldots, \pi_2 \left( A_N^\prime \right) \right\}
> $$
> of $\mathscr{A}_Y$ covers $Y$.

> Therefore, the collection
> $$
> \left\{ A_1, A_2, A_3, \ldots \right\} \cup \left\{ A_1^\prime, \ldots, A_N^\prime \right\} 
> $$
> is a countable subcollection of $\mathscr{A}$ that also covers $X \times Y$. Thus, it follows that $X \times Y$ is Lindelof.

Is this proof correct? If so, is my write-up of the proof clear enough too? Or, is there something wrong?

PS:

I think I can figure out where I have gone wrong.

> As
> $$ 
> X = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \pi_1 \left( A_n \right), 
> $$
> so we have
> \begin{align}
> X \times Y &= \pi_1^{-1} (X) \\
> &= \pi_1^{-1} \left( \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \pi_1 \left( A_n \right) \right) \\
> &= \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty  \pi_1^{-1} \left( \pi_1 \left( A_n \right) \right) \\
> &\supset \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty  A_n, \qquad \tag{1} 
> \end{align}
> and since the mapping $\pi_1 \colon X \times Y \longrightarrow X$ need not be injective, therefore the inclusion in (1) above need not be an equality, thus showing that the sets $A_1, A_2, A_3, \ldots$ need not cover $X \times Y$.

> A similar argument shows that the sets $A_1^\prime, \ldots, A_N^\prime$ need not cover $X \times Y$.

Am I right?

Comment: If this proof is valid then it seems to me that along the same lines it can be proved that the product of two Lindelof-spaces is again Lindelof. This however is not the case (see the answer of Henno on the linked question).

Comment: @Vera but where exactly OP is doing wrong. I’m just curious. I think in construction of $\mathscr{A}_X$ and $\mathscr{A}_Y$.

Comment: @user264745 See my answer on the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof does not work.

> Therefore, the collection
> $$
> \left\{ A_1, A_2, A_3, \ldots \right\} \cup \left\{ A_1^\prime, \ldots, A_N^\prime \right\} 
> $$
> is a countable subcollection of $\mathscr{A}$ that also covers $X \times Y$.

The collection is indeed countable but there is no guarantee that it covers $X\times Y$.

For each point $(x,y)\in X\times Y$ we can find sets $A_i=U_i\times V_i\in\mathcal A$ and $A_j^{\prime}=U_j^\prime\times V_j^\prime\in\mathcal A$ such that $x\in\pi_1(A_i)=U_i$ and $y\in\pi_2(A_j^{\prime})=V_j^\prime$.

So $(x,y)\in U_i\times V_j^\prime$, but there is no guarantee that $U_i\times V_j^\prime\in\mathcal A$.

Comment: This tiny mistake are not visible by naked eyes.

Comment: @user264745 You might need covered eyes to see that there is no covering :-).

Comment: @Vera thank you so much for taking time answering my question so diligently! Can you please also take a look at my PS?

Comment: What you are saying in your PS is correct. In general we have $B\subseteq f^{-1}(f(B))$ with equality if $f$ is injective.